# Inserting multiple data to SQL server using While loop via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

the idea is to insert the same data to SQL DB $quantity times
it mean that if i have quantity = 10 the SQL query need to insert the same data 10 times 
the problem is that always i have one record  more 
mean if i have the quantity=2 i will have 3 records
if I have it to 1 i will have 2 record and so

```
$i=1; 
while ($i<="$quantity")   
{
  $sql="INSERT INTO arivage (ID_Ship, Date_ariv, Date_achat, prov_id, Sph, cyl, Prod_type, Pord_color)  
       VALUES ('', '$date', '$date1', '$prov_id', '$sph', '$cyl', '$Prod_type', '$Prod_color')";
  mysql_query($sql);      
  $i++;
}
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

i have the sql connection and closing in the code too.

Comment: First of all, why would you use "$quantity" instead of a normal variable `$quantity`?

Comment: More or less there are unique key constraints in your table. Also Move your error checking block **if(!mysql_query...** inside **while()**.

Answer (score 1):

If you always have one record too many, that probably means your quantity value is not correct (?).

Also, this is not related to your problem, you should use `while($i<=$quantity)` instead of `while($i<="$quantity")`. You do not need the `"`s

This first block is ok:

```
$i=1; 
while ($i<="$quantity")   
{
    $sql="INSERT INTO arivage (ID_Ship, Date_ariv, Date_achat, prov_id, Sph, cyl, Prod_type, Pord_color)  
        VALUES ('', '$date', '$date1', '$prov_id', '$sph', '$cyl', '$Prod_type', '$Prod_color')";
    mysql_query($sql);      
    $i++;
}
```

The next if statement executes your query AGAIN, meaning you insert one too many rows. Removing the entire if statement would solve your "one too many rows is inserted" problem.

```
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Alternatively, change your while loop to:.

```
$i=1; 
while ($i<="$quantity")   
{
    $sql="INSERT INTO arivage (ID_Ship, Date_ariv, Date_achat, prov_id, Sph, cyl, Prod_type, Pord_color)  
    VALUES ('', '$date', '$date1', '$prov_id', '$sph', '$cyl', '$Prod_type', '$Prod_color')";
    if(!mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Hi, i am  sure that the Quantity is correct. if i fill the form with the quantity = 4 i will have 5 records, if i fill it with 6 i will have 7By the way i try without the " and na thing change.

Comment: If i move the if(!mysql_query... inside while() inside the while loop i will get 2 more records,in mean if i have quantity=2 i wll get :5 records.LOL

Comment: If you move it inside the loop, then remove your other mysql_query($sql) call.

Right now you are executing mysql_query($sql) a $quantity amount of times inside your loop, and then afterwards you execute mysql_query another time.. outside the loop.

You should either REMOVE the if(!mysql_query) statement completely, or move it inside the loop and remove the other mysql_query statement :)

Comment: Yes removing the if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
 solve the Problem. But i will not have an error message if the query is not inserted. There is a way to add this error message?

Comment: Yep, see updated version - your main problem was that you had mysql_query() twice. Having the if-statement INSIDE the loop is fine, but you have to remove your other mysql_query statement. :)